# Jquery mobile toggle button data-theme on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a buttons of a certain class

```
<div class="prog-day">
    <div class="prog-clear" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="b">Clear</a>
    </div>  
    <p></p>
</div
```

and I want to toggle the theme color onclick. The toggle ID changes and does the data-theme letter but the color doesn't change. This is all the things (trigger,create, refresh) I've tried based upon other posts

```
$(".prog-day a").click(function() {
    console.log("clicked a day button");
    progToggle = $(this).attr("progToggle");
    if ( progToggle == "1"  ) {
        $(this).attr("data-theme","b").refresh;
        $(this).attr("progToggle","0");
        $(this).trigger('create');
        $(this).trigger('refresh');
        $('.prog-day p').html($(this).attr("progToggle")+$(this).attr("data-theme"));
        progToggle = $(this).attr("progToggle");
     }
     else {
        $(this).attr("data-theme","d").refresh;
        $(this).attr("progToggle","1");
        $(this).trigger('create');
        $(this).trigger('refresh');
        $('.prog-day p').html($(this).attr("progToggle")+$(this).attr("data-theme"));
        progToggle = $(this).attr("progToggle");
    }           
});
```

What am I missing here. Am I better off skipping this JQM stying stuff and just do it myself? I'd actually like the buttons to toggle on the down press, not the release. Perhaps you could fiddle with http://jsfiddle.net/PLx8v/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for equality, make sure your if-statement has 3 equal signs

```
if( progToggle === '1' ) {}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, and it depends on whether or not you require strict equality (same value and same type).